# How to open URL in an Activity (instead of a new browser)?

Tags: java, android

> Can anyone please help me check my code to see why it cannot be
>   launched in the app itself but directs me to a browser? ): Thanks!!

**MAIN ACTIVITY.JAVA**

```
package com.intelligami.androidwebviewapp;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://intelligami.com/submitqn");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new com.intelligami.androidwebviewapp.MyAppWebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //hide loading image
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show webview
            findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }});


}
private class MyWebViewClient extends MyAppWebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();

    /** Setting a share intent */
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

/** Returns a share intent */
private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Convert Website to Android Application");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT," Vist www.AndroidWebViewApp.com if you Want to Convert your Website or Blog to Android Application");
    return intent;
}


}
```

**MY APP VIEW CLIENT. JAVA**

```
package com.intelligami.androidwebviewapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("intelligami.com/submitqn")) {
        return false;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
}
```

Where is the error? :D

It keeps opening up in the browser.

Answer (score 4):

In the following line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
```

you're asking Android to open a URL using the intent constant `ACTION_VIEW` - so it defaults to the external browser.

Here a full example (taken [from here](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/)) that shows how to open the url using a WebViewClient:

```
package com.paresh.webviewclientdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/*
 * Demo of creating an application to open any URL inside the application and clicking on any link from that URl
should not open Native browser but  that URL should open in the same screen.
 */
public class WebViewClientDemoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
  {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
}
```

Comment: I"m really new to this. So in order to make my code working, what should i change the intent to??

Comment: @JavierNg see the method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` in the example I posted, note that it doesn't use any intent!

Comment: public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("intelligami.com/submitqn")) {
            return true;
        }


So just like that?

Comment: @JavierNg no, did you look in the example I posted ?

Comment: I did and I copied paste the entire thing but it didn't work